# What shortcut to use to implement a function?

Tags: c++, rider, jetbrains-rider

Using Rider with C++ when I type the function declaration in header file, is there a keyboard shortcut to implement this in cpp file in one step without using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> ?

Comment: Since it exists as an alternative in the menus, it should be possible to configure such a shortcut in the settings.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning a shortcut for "Generate definitions" is not possible at the moment, but there is a feature request that should address this: [RIDER-51789](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-51789)